# Using count without aggregate

Tags: t-sql

I have a checkbox in our application that can have 1 of 3 options:

- Checked (True)
- Not Checked (False)
- Use Customer (Account) settings (from a checkbox above that would then grey out the checkbox.

[image: Check/Uncheck/Nothing Checked]

If the "Use Customer..." box is checked, the box with the arrow pointing to it greys out & the value is deleted from the database.
If it's checked, "True"
If it's not checked but "Use Customer..." is not checked, "False"
If "Use Customer..." is checked, there is no record.

My issues is pulling the SQL for it.  I can pull the TRUE/FALSE value with no issues.  I'm stuck trying to get the t-sql to return SOMETHING if the record is blank.

Currently I have this that works fine:

```
CASE when cb.tvalue.value('declare namespace y="http://schemas.xyzpdg.com/framework/resources";y:Item[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'True' THEN 'Checked'
        when cb.tvalue.value('declare namespace y="http://schemas.xyzpdg.com/framework/resources";y:Item[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'False' THEN 'Unchecked'
    END AS [CheckboxValue]--
```

I've tried using:

```
When COUNT(cb.tvalue.value('declare namespace y="http://schemas.xyzpdg.com/framework/resources";y:Item[1]', 'varchar(25)')) = 0 then 'Use Customer...'
```

But when I use that I of course get a the infamous ..."***invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."***
error.  And I can't use XML as a GROUP BY.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged tsql?

Comment: You put a lot of effort into describing a user interface that seems to be irrelevant to the question but don't show us the xml that you're apparently trying to work with?

Comment: I apologize.  I thought I did include the t-sql code above.  It appears that i-one understood it though.  Thank you for your kind & considerate reply.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it seems that either you may use `exist` xml type method or simply `else` branch of the case statement, see sample:

```
declare @xml xml;
--set @xml = '<Test><Item>False</Item></Test>';
--set @xml = '<Test><Item>True</Item></Test>';
set @xml = '<Test />';

select
    case
        when @xml.value('(/Test/Item)[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'True' then 'Checked'
        when @xml.value('(/Test/Item)[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'False' then 'Unchecked'
        when @xml.exist('(/Test/Item)[1]') = 0 then 'Use Customer...'
    end [CheckboxValue];

select
    case
        when @xml.value('(/Test/Item)[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'True' then 'Checked'
        when @xml.value('(/Test/Item)[1]', 'varchar(25)') = 'False' then 'Unchecked'
        else 'Use Customer...'
    end [CheckboxValue];
```